# Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference

Tags: java, android

I am a student in IT and i'm still learning java and android developement.
i'm testing with some udp traffic between a desktop app and a android app.
but every time I try to run the android app it gives this error message :

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference

this is the code of the UDP client

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.SocketAddress;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Client extends Activity {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
    int bufSize = 4096;
    int port = 12345;
    DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(port);
    sock.setReceiveBufferSize(bufSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];

    while (true) {
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, bufSize);
        sock.receive(p);
        Log.d("Client", "Received: " + new String(p.getData()));
    }
    }finally{}
    }
    }
```

the code may contain some parts that may not work, but it gives no errors.

I just want to know why the VM won't start.

grtz

Comment: which line of code gives that error?

Comment: none, I'ts just when I want to run the code this error comes in the console (in eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my error.
I used the android project like a java app, with a main function. this gave the problem of no being able to deploy the vm.
the code hade to be in the oncreate function of the activity instead of in a main function.
thanks for the help.

grtz

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your Java SDK wasn't installed correctly.

Try and see if java is in your system PATH. You can try javac -version command on your terminal. If that produces the same error, then you need to add it to your path.

Also, this guy seems to have had the same problem as yours, check that [link](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/):

Comment: if I do that, i get the version number : 1.7.0_02

Comment: Still strikes me as an issue with not being able to get to the JVM. Try the link I added.

Comment: could it be a problem with 32 and 64 bit both installed? and I'll check your link, thanks for your response

Comment: Yes, I personally prefer if I have only one version installed. It will clear up a whole lot of mess and annoying problems like these..

Comment: ok, so wich one would you recomend , 32 or 64 ? and i followed the steps on your link , but it didn't solve anything. but thanks anyway. I hope to find a solution quickly.

Comment: 32 bit because all 32 bit applications can also run on 64 bit machines anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps in order on UBUNTU 12.04LTS:

1. chmod 755 eclipse.desktop
2. Check `javac -version`
3. Find the correct path for javac
4. Find correct path for JDK
5. Add using vi the following lines in the top of file `/opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini`  :

   ```
   -vm
   /usr/bin  /*if javac is in /usr/bin */
   /usr/share/jdk7/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin /*if this is the path for JDK */
   ```